# Visit, student, fiancée visa for the UK

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, colombia

I have a girlfriend in Colombia.
We want to take the relationship to the next stage.
I have asked her to visit me to see what she thinks about a cold country and she how she feels about a life together.
She wants to be a student and come here and study English.

I think that is difficult because she cannot afford to fund herself and I will have to. 
I have read that fiancée visas are notoriously difficult to get, and anyway, we are not at that stage yet.
I am thinking a tourist visa and just see how our relationship develops.  I've read some horror stories and I want to do things the right way.
I am English born and bred.

Comment: The long-term visas are better fodder for our [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) site, but the student visa question is one we can answer here.

Comment: @user75790 What is your question? You can find detailed information on visa applications here https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa and https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF

Comment: VTC, unclear, and OP has not returned since posting this question, and has not clarified what exactly he's asking (so it's either unclear, too broad, or opinion based)